# Detecting Calendar Events using the Google Cloud Natural Language service

Tags: google-cloud-nl

Tried the Google Cloud Natural Language example. It worked nicely but I want it to be able to detect calendar events such as:

"Appointment at the Kendall Building at 800 Florida Ave NE on June 28th from 7p to 8p."

Would be nice to get the date/time categorized.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a new feature request. Please open a new Natural Language API issue at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests. Make sure to select "Feature Request" instead of "Bug" in issue type.